# How do I get 6 ATB slots?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

In FFXIII-2, I unlocked the Ultima Arrow and Meteor Javelin skills. Apparently, I need to have all the 6 ATB slots to be able to use them. But no matter how many crystarium levels I get, I no longer get the "+1 ATB slot" option when I receive a crystarium bonus.

So, how do I get all the ATB slots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultima Arrow and Meteor Javelin don't require six ATB segments: they are what's known as [full ATB skills](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Full_ATB_Skill), and require the entire ATB gauge, whatever the gauge's length is. For example, you can see Noel use Meteor Javelin with only 5 ATB segments in this video:

But, to answer your question, Serah and Noel both have weapons you can create post-game—*Sagittarius* and *Mac an Luin*, respectively—that will increase the ATB gauge by one. To craft them, you need:

- 2 × Trapezohedron
- 1 × Phoenix Blood
- 1 × Izanami (for Sagittarius) or 1 × Vajradanda (for Mac an Luin)

The trapezohedrons drop from the Long Gui in Archlyte Steppes *-??? AF-* when it's sunny, phoenix blood comes from Pantopoda in the later gates (like Academia *-500 AF-*, [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GUGFgtDVU) shows what they look like), and the base weapons are sold by Chocolina in Academia *-500 AF-*.

Once you have the required materials, Chocolina will craft them for you in Archlyte Steppes *-??? AF-*.

Comment: How weird... I could swear that those skills were never visible in my skills list... I'll check it out later. Thanks!

Comment: @Omega Did you select them during a crystarium expansion? You don't get them for free. Also make sure that no other abilities are queued, you're in the right roles (Ravager for Serah, Commando for Noel), and look at the bottom of the abilities list (IIRC, you can easily scroll past them and back to the top of the list if you're too quick).